# Spiritual gifts and their exercise within today's Catholic Church

Tags: catholicism, 1-corinthians, spiritual-gifts

Regarding the apostle Paul's discussion of spiritual gifts (τὰ πνευματικὰ χαρίσματα) in 1 Corinthians 12-14, he uses the words ".....when you come together" (1 Cor. 14:26). Is he referring to the exercise and manifestation of spiritual gifts within the celebration of the Eucharist during his time? If so, should these gifts be exercised in today's Eucharistic celebrations, and if so, how? Perhaps the apostle is citing the exercise of these gifts within a different context (e.g., the Agape which preceded the Eucharist - more akin to a "charismatic prayer group" outside the Mass).

What does the Catholic Church teach on this matter? Have these gifts (prophecy, tongues, interpretation, etc.) ceased, or are they still of great value today within the Church?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview of what this site is about, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). In particular, this site is not about individual views, but about what groups and denominations of Christians believe and teach. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) I would suggest editing your question to ask what the Catholic Church teaches about this rather than what potential answerers think abut it themselves. Meanwhile, I do hope you'll stick around!

Answer (score 2):

I'm only a novice, but I have been researching this subject lately and I would be happy to provide you with what little insight I can.

Different Catholic churches will have different positions on cessation vs continuation.

Typically Catholic churches hold a view point of cessation, however, Pope Francis in particular has been increasingly accepting of Charismatic Catholics (the word "Charismatic" here is implying that they believe in the gifts from 1 Corinthians) and he has invited them to the upcoming jubilee.

http://georgiabulletin.org/news/2014/06/pope-invites-charismatics-vatican-2017-jubilee/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catholic_Charismatic_Renewal

Hope it helps!

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for contributing.  I see you've taken the [tour]; if you'd like to learn more please take a look at [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Bible, in 1 Corinthians 7:7, shows us that everyone, "has a particular gift [charisma] from God, one of one kind and one of another."

The Catholic Church teaches about charisms in the Catechism of the Catholic Church (CCC), paragraphs 798 - 801:

They have a purpose:  Through the charisms, the Holy Spirit, "makes the faithful 'fit and ready to undertake various tasks and offices for the renewal and building up of the Church.' (CCC 798)

They are good: "Whether extraordinary or simple and humble, charisms are graces of the Holy Spirit which directly or indirectly benefit the Church, ordered as they are to her building up, to the good of men, and to the needs of the world." (CCC 799)

We must welcome them: "Charisms are to be accepted with gratitude by the person who receives them and by all members of the Church as well. They are a wonderfully rich grace for the apostolic vitality and for the holiness of the entire Body of Christ, provided they really are genuine gifts of the Holy Spirit and are used in full conformity with authentic promptings of this same Spirit, that is, in keeping with charity, the true measure of all charisms." (CCC 800)

They must be discerned: "It is in this sense that discernment of charisms is always necessary. No charism is exempt from being referred and submitted to the Church's shepherds. 'Their office [is] not indeed to extinguish the Spirit, but to test all things and hold fast to what is good,' (1 Thessalonians 5:12,19-21) so that all the diverse and complementary charisms work together "for the common good." (CCC 801)

They are to be used: St. John of the Cross gives insights into the wise, humble and helpful use of charisms.

Where are Charisms in the Bible?
The Bible lists many charisms, including:
1 Corinthians chapter 12 lists gifts of Service, Wisdom, Knowledge, Faith,  Healing,  Miracles, Prophecy, Discernment of Spirits, Tongues, Interpretation of Tongues, Helping, Administration, Teaching, and Pastoring.

Romans 12:6-8 lists gifts of Prophecy, Ministry, Teaching, Exhortation, Giving, Leadership, and Mercy.

The church has never taught cessation and the gifts still exist